# [Windows] Как установить чистую консоль PHP

Tags: windows, php

Цель такая, у меня Win XP, мне не нужен доступ по локал хосту нужно всего запустить C:\php\php.exe pars.php скачал PHP с сайта выполняю в cmd команду он говорит запустить php, разрешаю а потом говорит что не является приложением win32.

подскажите что не так?

Comment: Возьмите нормальный инсталлер с офф сайта и установите с него. Он сам пропишет пути в PATH и дальше в консоли можно будет набирать 

    php имя_файла.php

и все будет работать

Comment: мне не нужен исталятор, для терминалов будет php, попробую с денвера вытащить бинарник

Answer (score 3):

Заканчивайте выдумывать.

[Командная строка PHP в Microsoft Windows](http://wayback.archive.org/web/20151115091439/http://php.net/manual/ru/install.windows.commandline.php).